# Javascript - Download XLSX Content from Servlet

Tags: javascript, excel, servlets, xlsx

I have servlet URL that provides the content in "application/vnd.ms-excel" format on clicking export button.Here my doubt is, i already getting the content from servr in "application/vnd.ms-excel" format, how to map that server response to workbook template?

Referred the below stackoveflow link which explains about download HTML table as XLSX file.

[HTML Table to Excel Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript)

**HTML table to XLSX:-**

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

        document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();

    }
})()
```

I hope that the question is clear, thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*" how to map that server response to workbook template"*

You don't the browser will do it for you. Depending on you browser and it's configuration will download the file or show a pop up asking if needs to be saved or opened.

Look at  [Extjs 4 downloading a file through ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499959/extjs-4-downloading-a-file-through-ajax-call/20500559#20500559)

you need to set

```
standardSubmit: true
```

something like this:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', { // this wolud be your form 
            standardSubmit: true,         // this is the important part 
            url: '../GenerateFileServlet' 
        });

        form.submit({
            params: {
                fileName: myFile
            }
        });
```

**NOTICE that I am doing a form submit and not an Ajax Request.**